# Rails 5 Nested forms update not creating new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am trying to build a nested form and having issues when using the edit page of the resource.  I can get the new action to work fine, but I am finding if I try to update the resource to include new sub-resource it doesn't save the subresources.

I am running rails 5.2 and have cocoon gem installed for the nested forms.

An `order` has many `cards`

Order Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Card Model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Orders Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.cards.build
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.cards.build
  end

  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to orders_path    
  end

  private
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:title, :price, cards_attributes: [:id, :title, :price, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Orders Edit View:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :cards do |card| %>
    <%= render 'card_fields', f: card %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association f, :cards, class: "add-cards" do %>
    <span>Add Card</span>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Orders form partial View:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :title, 'Card Description', class: "g-mb-10" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control form-control-md g-brd-gray-light-v7 g-brd-lightblue-v3--focus g-rounded-4 g-px-20 g-py-12" %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association f, class: "remove-quals u-link-v5 d-flex align-items-center g-color-lightblue-v3 g-ml-30" do %>
    <span class="g-ml-15">Remove Card</span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now if I add `@order.cards.build` to the `edit` action it works, but if no new card is added it still creates an empty record.  Also if I change 
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true`
to
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['price'].blank? }`

This is works as long as none of the other items are being updated at the same time.

Ideally, When someone goes to edit order a new card shouldn't be visible till someone clicks add card.

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found my problem.

Edit view (add div with id of cards)

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>

  <div id="cards">

  <%= f.fields_for :cards do |card| %>
    <%= render 'card_fields', f: card %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association f, :cards, class: "add-cards" do %>
    <span>Add Card</span>
  <% end %>

  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller removed the `@order.cards.build` from the edit action.

Reason for the div, is the JS was inserting the fields for outside the actual form.